# Particle system for three.js as npm package

Tags: javascript, npm, module, three.js, particle-system

Is there any particle system for three.js that can be used as npm package (with import, without global namespace pollution)?

Edit: I want to use it as a module in a webpack bundling system. (without the need for global namespace variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. npm [shader-particle-engine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shader-particle-engine), github: https://github.com/squarefeet/ShaderParticleEngine

In general, the Three.js ecosystem is low quality, and if you want a package published to npm you have to do it yourself, and probably remove a lot of globals before you do :)

Comment: Thanks! I cannot make it work out of the box. It uses THREE global variable and does not import it as a module.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right I had to fork it and remove the global variables :P https://github.com/AndrewRayCode/ShaderParticleEngine/commit/0cd6780ae03d6d524a325622a4549b3bbc560e0b this is what I have in package.json ` "shader-particle-engine": "git://github.com/AndrewRayCode/ShaderParticleEngine.git#forever",`

Comment: I'm not sure such a broad dismissal of the entire community is adequate here. There is actually quite a lot of high-quality code surrounding three.js. I guess you just wanted to say that the three.js ecosystem still relies on older paradigms and hasn't adopted npm and modules yet?

Comment: @AndyRay oh that's you :). I saw you commenting on that exact globals topic on that library. And that library is out of maintainance as I saw. You should publish modules adjusted version of shader-particle-engine as an npm package :).

Comment: Cool. ` "shader-particle-engine": "git://github.com/AndrewRayCode/ShaderParticleEngine.git#for‌​ever",` in package.json works like a charm.

Comment: I don't think it's an officially dead project which is why I don't want to take over the npm namespace. Squarefeet shows up every now and then